# HTACCESS - Server 404 for "deny from" instead of 403

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to server `404` instead of `403` when matched with "`deny from`"?

For **example**:

```
<Files *>
order deny,allow

deny from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

This will normally server a 403. But I want to server 404.